# Starwind iSCSI shrink device

Tags: storage-area-network, iscsi, starwind

I have a 600GB device setup and attached via iSCSI using the free version of Starwind. I've found I'll need to use 300 GB of the host drive for another purpose and would like to resize the 600GB image down to 300GB. There is only 200GB of data on the NTFS filesystem and it's not fragmented. Is there a method to do this?
Would be great if I could avoid copying all the data to a USB HDD to re-create the drive.

Regards,

Comment: Search this site for "shrink NTFS partition", e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/223344/shrink-ntfs-partition-windows-2003

Comment: Do you know if I shrink the NTFS partition if the .img file created by Starwind would also shrink?

Answer (score 3):

The StarWind image format cannot be shrunk. I wound up using the StarWind iSCSI initiator with the Windows Server iSCSI target (the Windows iSCSI initiator kept dropping out). The Windows iSCSI target uses VHD files which supports shrinking the filesystem and the disk image.